# How to save article ID's a user LIKES in Cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

Let's say you have a blog and a user can "Like" and article. On your average site with a userbase your user would be logged in and this data would likely be stored in a Database but with something like a Wordpress blog where your user is likely not logged into an account, to keep track if they "Like" an article or not you likely store it's id into a Cookie for them. At least that's how most existing solutions do it.

My issue with this is all the solutions I have seen so far create a new cookie for each article a user likes. If you have a large blog with hundreds or thousands of articles and say a user likes 150 articles, that's 150 cookies being sent with each request. Just the thought of this scares me.

My idea is to store each Article ID into the same cookie in eaither JSON format or possibbly just the ID's separated with a |

I would then have to extract all the ID's into an array or something so it adds slightly more processing but would cut down on the HTTP requests

I would love to hear other thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: `JSON` would be good option to go with then you can use `json_decode()` to decode the data from the cookie on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the server need to know about it? What if you stored it purely client-side, with `localStorage`?

Comment: That could possibly be an option

Comment: This is the localStorage object store plugin that I use http://upstatement.com/blog/2012/01/jquery-local-storage-done-right-and-easy/

Comment: This looks really interesting, I have played around with local storage in the past (just experiments) I have been reluctant to use it because it seems only some browser support it but I really like the Cookie fallback that this has, thanks for sharing, what an awesome resource

Answer (score 0):

unless you do `JSON.stringify()`  you'll need to separate them with a | then explode it into an array. and use another separator if you need to store more than one piece of data for each 'liked' article, extracting the data into a multidimensional array which you can process with a loop or two.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the likes in the PHP session rather than cookies. Using the session you won't run into problems relating to too many cookies. Also, you can't trust cookie data because it may have been tampered with, you need to verify it every time you access it.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood, I cannot do that.  There is no persistent method of keeping track of which user liked which articles (no user accounts)

Comment: You don't need a user account to maintain a session variable. The session is unique to the user due to the session ID cookie.

Comment: A sessions is active for a very short time, not for months

Comment: A session exists until the session ID cookie expires or until the server setting wants it to. It can last as long as any other cookie. You can set the expiry datetime just as you can with other cookies.